# Can client-side .js decryption enhance security?

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

By a parent-company-wide mandate, I need to structure my web-app that any personally identifiable client information will only be shown to users if the user clicks on a "View" button in the field.

(This isn't a high-level security thing, and it doesn't need ultra-high level encryption.  All authenticated and authorized of the app will be able to view the data.  The mandate is for the data to be stored encrypted and not decrypted until just prior to display to the end-user.  The intent is to eliminate any employee from having easy access to a screen full of sensitive info that could make large-scale information stealing easy for even tech un-savvy.  "Locks keep honest people honest.")

The obvious challenge of doing this in javascript is that both the ciphertext and the key would need to be used to decrypt the value, and they'd both have to come from the server(s) via HTTPS.  Implemented poorly, the web-app could make the encrypted date *easier* to get in clear-text since it could expose the keys and shared secrets used by the encryption algorithm.

At minimum, I can send a guid to the client as a limited time one-use-only token to allow them to access an HTTPS web service that would return one item of clear-text data per click of a view button.  (Which technically does nothing to enhance security except throttling the speed that the data could be stolen.)

Are there known methods for web apps to use splitting data between an initial request, and a later AJAX request to enhance the data security?  I certainly *could* roll my own system for the AJAX view requests that could use things like time of day, session key, etc. to validate requests, but I'm not sure if that would really get me any benefit -- I would still end up with two options:  Responding to the AJAX request via HTTPS with the clear text, or sending both the cipher text and the decryption keys/secrets to a browser to decrypt with.

NOTE:  Keep in mind, the only point here is to stop non-techie employees from being tempted to do bad things with "easy-stealing" data.  I'm totally comfortable if anyone wants to debunk or prove whether any techniques actually benefit security or are just busy-work that are equally vulnerable.

Comment: I don't see how a non-techie can get the data even if it is not encrypted. You're saying that you have to do an Ajax request nevertheless which means that they can't just inspect the page source to grab all data. They would have to send those Ajax requests themselves (or simply automate the UI which would also break your "encrypted" data distribution).

Comment: It sounds like you have already solved your problem - i.e. you load the initial page, without the PII (personally-identifiable info), then later, you do a separate Ajax request to obtain the PII in response to the user clicking "View". For both requests (the initial one and the Ajax request) you could do them over HTTPS.

Comment: You can either trust the users with the data, or not. Futzing around with AJAX or encryption as you describe sounds like busy work to me. The inspector markup will always contain the data, and adding an AJAX endpoint might make it _much_ easier for some to harvest the data.

Comment: Any kind of JS based (A.K.A. not HTTPS) encryption for a webpage sounds like a waste of time to me.

Comment: I agree with @DigitalDesignDj, you aren't actually gaining any security.

Comment: @LukePark - I'm a pragmatist.  Security distills down to making sure that the effort needed to get to the info is greater than the value of the data, and also greater than the effort to get the data some other way.  Since the value of the data isn't huge, and there are plenty of other way to get the same data, I'm just looking to make sure this app isn't the weak link in the chain.

Comment: @GreenGiant & DigitalDesignDj I think you guys are right.  I think the only client-side decryption I need is just HTTPS. (TLS1.2)